# How do I keep a CSS container the same size?

Tags: html, css

I have 6 images next to each other in two rows. I used a CSS container to center it (couldn't use padding). However, when I shrink the screen, since the margin is set to auto, the container shrinks opposed to the blank space around the container. You can see this [here](https://www.netatlantic.com/featuredindustries/) . The blue is just there to show the container. The images need to stay in that order until it becomes physically impossible for them to stay there. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advanced!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Featured Industries</title>
</head>
<style>
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 66%;
    height: 625px;
    border: 3px solid #0026E3;
    padding: 0px;
}
.img {
    float: left;
}
a:hover img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 31px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 31px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 31px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the container size in `%`, which means, in this case, it will always be 66% of the document width that matches the window's width. That's why, it shrinks when you change the window size. If you set the container width to double the width of the images, it will not shrink.

So, according to your example, this will work:

```
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 622px; /* (311 x 2) */
    height: 625px;
    border: 3px solid #0026E3;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Now you have to solve another problem when they don't fit in the windows, like in mobile phones for example. Then you can use [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). So now let's add another rule for when there is no space for the 2 images column.

```
/* This is the default behavior (mobile first) */
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 311px; /* 1 column by default */
    height: 625px;
    border: 3px solid #0026E3;
    padding: 0px;
}

/* Let's now modify the container size when there is space */
/* for 2 image columns */
@media screen and (min-width: 622px) {
    .center {
        width: 622px; /* 1 column by default */
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the prefered notation for comments in css is `/* a comment */`

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres, edited, I use SCSS, that's why I was confused

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to let you know that there is not a different site for mobile version this is the only version. I changed the code and am using this [<style>
}
 @ media screen and (max-width : 1500px) {
    .center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 933px;
    height: 625px;
    border: 3px solid #0026E3;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) {
    .center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 311px;
    height: 625px;
    border: 3px solid #0026E3;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
}  On an iPhone it shows  two 3 rows of 2

Comment: here is a link of the code along with a view of my iPhone 6 https://www.netatlantic.com/featuredindustries/images thank you

Comment: @SethC: I didn't say anything about a mobile version. What I'm trying to say it's that your styles should react to different screen sizes, like mobile phones, iPad, etc. The problem is in your media queries. `max-width: 1500px` means that it will apply that styles to all sizes under 1500px, so 360px will also be affected. I encourage you to read a bit more about media queries and `min-width`, `max-width`, etc. If this answer is correct, then mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this class:

```
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 933px;
    height: 625px;
    border: 3px solid #0026E3;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

If you set the width to the 66% it will depend on the father width, bit if you just set it to a number of px it will remain the same size

Comment: Thank You very much! Now i noticed that once the screen in shrunk down to far it continues to stay the same size. Is there a way to have it stay the same size while on the screen but once it goes off of the screen it can change? (it could become 3 rows of 2 images and then just 6 rows of 1 image)

Comment: @SethC. check my answer, for homework I left the 3 columns of 2 images

Comment: As Tom pointed in his answer, the best approach is using media queries, which allow you to apply CSS rules taking in count the screen size, for example